# str.decode('hex') in python3, doesn't return the same with codecs or binascii on python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.7

In PY2, i have the following code

```
h = '%x' % n
s = ('0'*(len(h) % 2) + h).zfill(length*2)
p = s.decode('hex')
```

Where
n=10920561661352709132212557111173638249950173732015881657298539050311200391549110548303562478673520599672107531797458446370644971784389781629994518008053754219010755978728797101180502114035533132873366378548272020105649766998247533890238098824744467281595553108172940941493774502868106307465006777909823196420561763398995691897240569190081920697565236701268406713

length=150

so p is

> > > p='\xa2]8\xf3-\xfe\x00\xe7\xff\x00\xd7\xad\x13\xe3\x01\x161\x1e\xa3\x86\xdc(l\xa1\x9b\xa56\xf4to\x00W\x8b\x11a|\xff\xe7B\x00\x15\x10\xc4\x8b\xff\xa0\r`\x00=\xa1G\xf3\x86\xbb\x060\xaa\x01\xc2\xc4\x00\x16m\xd4\xff4\x94\xbf\x06\x05\xc5\xef\xff\xd0F\x01 \xa3\x01\xff\t\x02\xec\x82\x06\xe7\x16aZP0\xfa\xff2\x98\xe7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0N\xd1\x00k\x9fE\x16\xff>\xe5V\x00\x89\x970Kg\x96\x8c\x00i\xc8\x86\xa2>\x05\x8b\xb3\xed\x00\xf0.b~\x87*\x12\xf4\t#\xf8\x00(a\xf1\xb9'

> > > print(p)
> > > `=�G�0���m��4������F ��W��aZP0��2���N�k�E�>�V��0Kg��iȆ�>����.b~�*�      #�(a�

Need to generate the same value of p in python 3

In PY3
I used

```
h = '%x' % n
s = ('0'*(len(h) % 2) + h).zfill(length*2)
p = codecs.decode(s, 'hex')
```

and get p as

p = b'\xa2]8\xf3-\xfe\x00\xe7\xff\x00\xd7\xad\x13\xe3\x01\x161\x1e\xa3\x86\xdc(l\xa1\x9b\xa56\xf4to\x00W\x8b\x11a|\xff\xe7B\x00\x15\x10\xc4\x8b\xff\xa0\r`\x00=\xa1G\xf3\x86\xbb\x060\xaa\x01\xc2\xc4\x00\x16m\xd4\xff4\x94\xbf\x06\x05\xc5\xef\xff\xd0F\x01 \xa3\x01\xff\t\x02\xec\x82\x06\xe7\x16aZP0\xfa\xff2\x98\xe7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0N\xd1\x00k\x9fE\x16\xff>\xe5V\x00\x89\x970Kg\x96\x8c\x00i\xc8\x86\xa2>\x05\x8b\xb3\xed\x00\xf0.b~\x87*\x12\xf4\t#\xf8\x00(a\xf1\xb9'

How to get the value of p as same using the py2?

Comment: They ARE the same.  The issue here is that you have a byte string with characters above chr(127).  The character `"\xf3"` does not have  a single representation.  If you want to print that, you have to tell Python how you want those to be displayed.  Do you want UTF-8?  You can try `print(p.encode('utf-8'))`  You can see that your Python 2 string prints garbage.   If you're on Windows, maybe you want `print(p.encode('cp1252'))`.

Comment: So how to convert that byte string to string that the PY2 generated

Comment: Python 2 generated garbage that depended on your terminal's character set.  Python 3 forces you to KNOW what you want.  So, what do you want?  You surely never used the printed value from Python 2, since as you can see many of the values print as unknown glyphs.  What are you going to DO with this string?